# Automatically reconnect to Twitter's Streaming API

Tags: node.js, twitter, stream

I am using node module Twit (https://github.com/ttezel/twit) to stream data from Twitter. My app update my users ranking based on their twitter activity so I am screening their tweet in rel time.
It should be streaming permanently so I'd like to prevent any connection issue. Is it possible to attempt to reconnect to the API if for some reason my app crashes?

What it the correct way to do this?

I am sure the following code is not recommended:

```
stream.on('disconnect', function (disconnectMessage) {
  console.log(disconnectMessage);
  stream.start();
})
```

Many thanks

Comment: Does the code above work?